# Vaex: How to add/append rows to a Vaem DataFrame

Tags: python, rows, vaex

How do you add data to a Vaex DataFrame?

I can see there is `add_column()`, but no `add/append_row()`

I'm looking to use Vaex instead of Pandas.

Answer (score 2):

I believe these is a concat method for this.

```
df = df_1.concat(df_2)
```

It's mentioned in the API Documentation as well.

Comment: thanks ... so you are saying i have to create a dataframe every time i need to add row... isnt this too expensive an operation ?

Comment: So that's how I did it when I wanted to do the same actually. Sadly never found a row append thing. It does sound operation expensive but umm... that's all I know. I'd actually love to know if you found something on the same lines.

Comment: the more i read vaex&dask they seem like readonly fast whole-set processing of large dataset!

Comment: the other idea i had was to create 10-20% large than required df/array and then convert it and save it and later reopen this new empty dataset. Then edit/update the data incrementally, BUT i couldnt find a way to EDIT/UPDATE specific cells or rows either. Vaex seem like readonly + computed cols large dataset lib

Comment: another option is if we can trick vaex to read from "lazy' .csv stream-file !? i.e. you add the data at the end of the stream. but how do you make receive lazy stream and reinterpret it !!

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your question, but wanted to correct concat A
To concatenate two dataframes, the API is similar to pandas.

to assign it to the same dataframe variable

```
df1 = vaex.concat([df1, df_new])
```

or

to assign it to a new dataframe variable

```
df3 = vaex.concat([df1, df2])
```